# QGIS not allowing alphanumeric labelling, can only use integers

Tags: label, maps, mapping, gis, qgis

Regular user of QGIS for moderate mapping needs. Currently using desktop version 3.24.0.

Tring to add labels to point and polygon shapefile layers. Never had an issue doing this before, but now I can only select the integer option indicated by '123'. The alphanumeric option usually indicated by 'abc' is no longer there, and i cannot create a label with any form of lettering as a result.

You can see below that the dropdown menu only has an option for integers:
[image: Screenshot]

Anyone else had this issue? Did you find a resolution?

Cheers,
R

Comment: I think your question is off-topic. This site is about programming. We have many sister sites (links on top right icon), one may be more relevant: https://gis.stackexchange.com/. The field is integer, so you cannot put alphanumeric. Just add a "name field", or change type.

Comment: Isn't because your layer has only ID (numeric) field? Try modify the attribute table and add an text field.